# How to do a fuzzy scan in Redis?

Tags: redis

Trying to obtain all values from Redis.

The key is:

```
key: mission:step:{missionId}:{yyMMdd} field：{userId} value：{progress}
```

I would like to get three columns: `mission_id` - `user_id` - `progress` to and put them to `Hive`/`MySQL`. The values of `mission_id` are different everyday.

How to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dude, Redis is a key-value store not a database. Give it the key and it will give you its value.

Comment: You know nothing, Jon @evilSnobu. https://redis.io/topics/indexes

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it will be a  slow operation. Redis [KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys) command lists all keys matched by a regex pattern.
But it is a O(N) operation as it scans each key in redis to match it against the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SCAN` command which is more safe than `keys` in production environment.

> Since these commands allow for incremental iteration, returning only a small number of elements per call, they can be used in production without the downside of commands like KEYS or SMEMBERS that may block the server for a long time (even several seconds) when called against big collections of keys or elements.

You can use `SCAN 0 MATCH your-key-pattern` to do loop query, and every next query's cursor is in the this time's reply, util the reply cursor is 0.

> SCAN is a cursor based iterator. This means that at every call of the command, the server returns an updated cursor that the user needs to use as the cursor argument in the next call.
>
> An iteration starts when the cursor is set to 0, and terminates when the cursor returned by the server is 0.